# Manifest.json multiple background services

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, manifest

I used the below in a Manifest v3 to create a Chrome extension.

```
"background": { 
  "service_worker": "js/background.js", 
  "type":"module" 
},
```

Can I put multiple `background.js` files in a manifest?

I did not found any information about this. Thanks for help!

Comment: Is your goal to create multiple service worker modules? If so, yes that's possible, see the documentation here: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/get-started/tutorial/service-worker-events

Answer (score 0):

You can not specify multiple background service workds directly in the background fied of the manifest.

To use multiple scripts you, should import them nto your main background service work

for example, if you have additional scripts use as

```
// in background.js
import './script1.js';
import './script2.js';
```